# Casting to int when generating a random distribution - Python

Tags: python, random

I was messing around with graphing random distributions and found faint, but distinct and regularly spaced, lines appear when I graphed a distribution created by int(random.random() * random.random()). Here is the code I was using:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

for i in range(50000):
    x.append(int(100*(random.random() + random.random())))
    y.append(int(100*(random.random() + random.random())))

plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.scatter(x,y,s=3)
```

And this is the graph I got:

[image: Scatter-plot of distribution with distinct faint lines]

If you take out the integer casting, then the whole thing looks as expected:

[image: Scatter-plot of distribution without integer casting]

Oddly enough, it seems that only the x-axis is responsible for the vertical lines, as removing the cast on the x-axis gets rid of the lines. The y-axis doesn't display any faint horizontal lines, but there are a couple darker lines.

[image: Scatter-plot with integer casting removed on the x-axis only]

Obviously the fainter lines have something to do with casting to integer, but why and how does that affect the overall distribution this way. Also, why is it only in the vertical direction and not applied symmetrically across both dimensions?

Comment: It seems like there are a number of ways this could happen.  Since these floats are binary, you may have found one of those binary-to-decimal edge cases.  Or it could be a flaw in the PRNG algorithm.  You might want to try this with SystemRandom as a comparison.

You could also generate your integers with random.choice(range(100))

Comment: Thanks, I tried SystemRandom, and got the same result. I agree with you that it is probably an edge case of some sort. I was just wondering if someone had some insight into this specific edge case to help satisfy my curiosity. There are definitely better ways to generate random distributions of integers than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely an artifact related how `matplotlib` is deciding which points to drop from the plot when the plot is too "crowded". For example, on my screen I got a plot with tightly spaced lines - see [image: plot with size=(12,12)] while decreasing the plot size to `(10, 10)` resulted in [image: this image].

Also, decreasing the number of points to 10000 (in my case=for my screen) resulted in line-free plot for `size=(12,12)`: [image: Plot with size=(12,12) and 10000 points]

---

As an experiment, let's plot a set of uniformly spaced set of points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))
plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), s=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the result for the uniformly spaced points]

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is correct. When I plot the uniformly spaced set of points, I get a different collection of lines. Thanks for your answer. I thought it would have a more interesting explanation than this, haha. That said, it is still interesting that it only happens if cast to integer, and not in the float version